# Can't ssh login from a remote network

Tags: linux, ssh, mac-osx, remote-access, opensuse

I relied on ssh to login to my home server from a laptop (both machines were on a local network). Now I am working away from home, so I tried to ssh login from the same laptop to the server's public IP address, but it tells me "connection has timed out". I tried turning the firewall off on the server (I can also login to the server with TeamViewer) and verifying that the public IP address I have for the server is correct via whatismyip.com, but I still can't ssh login. Any suggestions on what to do next? Btw, the server is running OpenSUSE and the laptop has macOS. Thanks!

Comment: You need to forward the port from your home router to the server.  The router doesn't magically know what device behind it you want to receive.

Comment: Hey. Thanks. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @yoonix pointed out in the comments: the problem was that the port designated for SSH needed to be forwarded from the router to the server.